# How does my browser interpret "<app-root>"?

Tags: html, angular, browser

I assume that `<app-root>` is from angular development.
However, I was under the impression that frameworks solve into html/js/css as they compile.

When I open a angular page, in the source code and go to the `<body>`, I can only see the `<app-root>` tag.
How does my browser read that?

Why can I not read the (html, should it not be?) source code?

Comment: Google for Angular bootstrap or equivalent.  Here are two links that might help: https://dev.to/casperns/how-angular-trigger-indexhtml-and-start-working-1l46 and https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-bootstrapping-application/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is a SPA (Single Page Application) framework. Basicaly, the app-root will be replaced in execution-time with the properly html/css/js when it's required, the whole thing is done internaly by the framework using javascript.

So, if you click to show the source code (CTRL + U on Windows), you will see only the app root. Of course, you can inspect the page with your browser console to see the "magic" going on.

You can understand better and more deep on the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#introduction-to-angular-concepts).